# selenium element click not working as expected

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I was trying to write an automated script to download some foreign exchange USD/CAD price historical data with selenium. These data are available at

https://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/historical/

The data I want to download select the **candlestick** options with **1 hour**, after manually selecting the 'Tick' Button and select 'Hour', this looks like:

[image]

And the **offer side** area becomes clickable. If I automated this process with selenium, the codes look like:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/historical/")

# wait for the frame to load and switch
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
iframe = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".mainContentBody iframe")))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

for pair in ["USDCAD"]:
    css_selector = "ul > li[data-group][data-instrument='{}/{}']".format(pair[:3], pair[3:])
    li_item = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_selector)))
    li_item.click()

    # Set the two options about candlestick
    candle_unit_menu_ele = driver.find_element_by_id(":i")
    candle_unit_menu_ele.click()

    candle_unit_ele = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, ":3"))
    candle_unit_ele.click()
```

However, after executing this script, you will find the USD/CAD button is selected, while the candle unit is not set to Hour, nor does the **offer side** section becomes available. Picture:

[image]

I am wondering why this is happening and how to have the expected outcome.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what does unit set to?

Comment: It should be set to hour @YuZhang

Comment: Which version of Selenium and Firefox are you on? I'm on Firefox 45.2 and Selenium 2.52. When I ran your code it works.

Comment: The Firefox version is 47.0.1, the selenium version is 2.53.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Edit:***

There may be an issue with it clicking the correct element. So after the line:

```
candle_unit_ele = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, ":3")))
```

Add:

```
candle_unit_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=':3']/div")
```

...to click the child div of the div with id `:3`.

So those two steps can now be:

```
# Set the two options about candlestick
candle_unit_menu_ele = driver.find_element_by_id(":i")
candle_unit_menu_ele.click()

candle_unit_ele_parent = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, ":3")))
candle_unit_ele = candle_unit_ele_parent.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=':3']/div")
candle_unit_ele.click()
```

Or:

```
candle_unit_ele = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=':3']/div")))
candle_unit_ele.click()
```

---

Btw, you've got a syntax error on the line:

```
candle_unit_ele = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, ":3"))
```

Needs a closing bracket:

```
candle_unit_ele = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, ":3")))
```

Also, while not an error, the line `for pair in ["USDCAD"]:` is unnecessary since you're not actually looping. Just `pair = "USDCAD"` is enough, unless you plan to loop over other currency options. But since they are radio buttons, you would only end up selecting the last one the loop runs.

Comment: Ok, I tried to switch to lower version of Firefox, but it didn't work. Then I tried switch to Chrome it worked out

Comment: Modified my answer to click a different element. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it was working for me:

```
   candle_unit_ele = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, ":3"))
   candle_unit_ele.click()
```

Replace your code above with:

```
   candle_unit_ele = driver.find_element_by_id(":3")
   candle_unit_ele.click()
```